# Ocaml, unkown operator Error: Unbound value >>|

Tags: dependencies, ocaml, operator-keyword

I was trying to install the DuckDuckGo API in OCaml, as detailed here : https://github.com/mwhittaker/duckduckgo-ocaml

After installing the dependencies, I try to execute the following piece of code (with `OCaml version 4.02.3`)

```
DuckDuckGo.query_record "ocaml" >>| function
| Ok response -> print_endline response.abstract
| Error _     -> print_endline "no abstract found"
```

but the operator `>>|` seems to be unkown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `open Async.Std` statement which should bring `>>|` in scope.